# Converting value

Tags: c++, file-io

What I want to try is converting each value in a string to double. Let me explain it via en example:

```
foo.txt
1.5 3 0.2 
6 12.4 16.2
```

I have a file with such a lines. I get these lines one by one by getline() function and assume I put each line in a *myLine* variable. Now I want to reach 1.5 3 and 0.2 separetely as a double and store it into `double a` variable. Is there anyone to know how could I do that ?
By the wayI do not have to get lines with getline(),if there is better way to do that.

**EDIT**

```
int main(){
    ifstream myfile("test.txt");
    string line;

    double d;
    if(myfile.is_open()){

        if(myfile.good()){
            while(getline(myfile,line)){
                   // example line : "0.1 0.5 0.9 0.23 0.12 145 23 12 40 160"
                for(int i=0;i<line.size();i++){ // I want to  store each value in the line into d for a time and print it out.
                    std::stringstream s(line); 
                    s>>d;
                    cout<<d<<endl;
                }
            }
        }


    }
    else{
        cout<<"check the corresponding file"<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The final nested for-loop isn't needed if all you want is the first number from each line. Clip out the loop (but keep the string stream, etc). If you want *all* the numbers from each line, the algorithm is still different, but without confirmation that is what your goal is I can't say for sure. Do you want to process each line, and in doing so, *all* numbers on that line?

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for reply. I want to read all values for a line one by one and store int into vector<double>.Make some operations on this line and then move on to second line of file until eof.Do you know how ?

Comment: Ok. that code is surprisingly easy to do. I'll post a response unless someone hangs it out there first.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double a, b, c;
cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

Unless you don't have a fixed number of doubles per line, then google `stringstreams`, that will do what you want.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::stringstream ss (line);

vector<double> result;
double a;
//read all the doubles in the line
while (ss >> a) {
    result.push_back(a);
}

//Now result contains the doubles in the line
//I'm sure there's a way to do that in less lines with insert iterators
```

Comment: ın the first 2 lines I have 1 number for each line and than there will be 10 number for eachline. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: Edited answer to give example with string streams

Comment: could you look at my edit ? I did it in this way but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::stringstream`:

```
std::string line = ......;

std::stringstream s(line);
double a,b,c;
s >> a >> b >> c;
```